# Can you instantiate an object inside another class?

Tags: php, class, oop

Is it possible to declare an object inside another class? The following code keeps giving me an error `nexpected 'new' (T_NEW)` error.

```
Class class1{
    public function doSomething(){
        $var = 3;
        return true;    
    }
}

Class class2{

    public $class1 = new class1();

    public function doSomethingElse(){
        if($class1->doSomething() == true){
            return 10;      
        }else{      
            return 13;
        }   
    }
}

//$obj = new class2();
```

I don't really want want to pass in the object through a constructor, because it's used inside other classes, so I'd have to pass it through multiple times. Is there a better method?

Comment: You cant' initialize a class property with anything that's resolved at runtime (like a new object, a call to a method, and so on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Constructor of your class to instantiate the other class.

```
Class class1
{
    public function doSomething() 
    {
        $var = 3;
        return true;    
    }
}

Class class2
{    
    protected $class1 = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->class1 = new class1();    
    }

    public function doSomethingElse() 
    {
        if ($this->class1->doSomething() == true) {
            return 10;      
        } else {      
            return 13;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to put the initialization in construction method.

```
Class class2{

    public $class1;

　　public function __construct() {
        $this->class1 = new class1();
    }


    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only initialize scalar values and arrays, use the constructor:

```
class Class2 {

  public $class1;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->class1 = new Class1();
  }

  ...
}
```